# How to use user input as an array name in C?

Tags: arrays, c

im making a game where users will learn a specific category of vocabulary. i'll first ask for the category of vocabulary they want to learn, save the category in a character array, and then use the array of the category name.

```
char Animals[10][11] = {"Eagle", "Cat", "Dog", "Rabbit", "Whale", "Snake", "Butterfly", "Dolphin", "Elephant", "Turtle"};

void askCategory() {
  printf("\nAnimals     Nature\n");
  printf("Clothes      Food\n");
  printf(" Fruit       Jobs\n");
  printf("\nWhich category of vocabulary would you like to learn? ");
  scanf("%s", category);
}

void question(){
  char userInput[15] = "";
  printf("\n\n%d.What does this picture represent? ",row + 1);
  scanf("%s", userInput);

  if(strcmp(userInput, ???)==0)
    printf("Correct!\n");
```

category is a gloabl character array. 'Animals' is one of the category.
for example the user chose the 'Animals' category, then how can i use category(which has stored 'Animals') in other situations eg.strcmp (comparing user input and one of the words in the Animals array)

Comment: To answer the question in the title: "How to use user input as an array name in C?" The answer is it's not possible. Once source code has passed the compiler, things like variables and their names doesn't really exists any more, only locations in memory. So it's not possible to use run-time user-input as names of symbols in the program. But this doesn't really describe the problem you're actually have, and the question you actually ask about.

Comment: You might need `stricmp` (Windows) or `strcasecmp` (Linux) and search the array in a loop.

Comment: You need to compare the input of the user to each array you want to access. Then set a pointer to that array. Kind of like (pseudo code): if user input == "animals" then pointer = animals; else if user input == "clothes" then pointer = clothes; end if etc.

Comment: If you need to compare user-input to an existing string in the code, like `Animals[i]` then use `strcmp` (as you seem to know about). If the strings are elements of an array, you need to loop over the array until you find the right string in the array. Use a status flag to keep track of the status, if the user input was found or not inside the loop. And remember that `strcmp` is case-sensitive.

Comment: Variable names exist solely for the benefit of the programmer. They are not for the user, they are not for the final executable. They only exist in the source code. Generally if you want the user to choose between different given alternatives, a plain number is likely the easiest to use. Then you can re-use that number as an array index later when fetching the data.

Comment: And if you want to use user input to figure out which array of many you want, you need to *map* a string to the array. For example using a structure containing the "name" of the array (as a string) and a pointer to the first element of the array. Then create an array of that structure, to map from the name to the array, and loop over that array to find the one you need.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As others already said, it is not possible to access the name of a C array / variable during runtime. But you can store pointers to your arrays alongside a name (as string) and length, and then compare the name-strings with the user input when the program is run (see code below).

Some notes what I changed and why:

1. Used `fgets` instead of `scanf`. With `scanf`, your program will likely crash  (and has a security bug) if the user enters more than 15 characters.
2. Used `strcasecmp` instead of `strcmp`, so that the user can enter the answer in lower case. It's called `stricmp` in Windows, hence the `#ifdef / #define`.
3. Changed the type of `Animals` from `char[10][11]` (a two-dimensional array where each entry has the same fixed number of bytes) to `char *[]` or equivalently `char **`. This is a one-dimensional array of pointers to strings, where each string can have a different length. This is important because the two-dimensional array type cannot be stored in the pointer inside the `named_array` struct, unless all arrays have the same string length limit.
4. Note of caution: `ARRAY_COUNT` works only on *arrays*, not on *pointers*. Because we store only a pointer in the `named_array` struct, we have to store the array's length as well, because the length information is lost when assigning the `Animals` array to the `data` member in the struct.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <strings.h> // strcasecmp()
#include <string.h> // strlen()

#define ARRAY_COUNT(a) ((sizeof a) / (sizeof a[0]))
#ifdef _WIN32
#define strcasecmp stricmp
#endif

typedef struct {
    const char *name;
    char **data;
    int count;
} named_array;

char *Animals[] = { "Eagle", /* ... */ };
char *Fruit[] = { "Apple", /* ... */ };
char *Clothes[] = { "Trousers", /* ... */ };

named_array all_arrays[] = {
    { "Animals", Animals, ARRAY_COUNT(Animals) },
    { "Fruit", Fruit, ARRAY_COUNT(Fruit) },
    { "Clothes", Clothes, ARRAY_COUNT(Clothes) },
};


void question(void){
  char userInput[15] = "";
  printf("What does this picture represent? ");
  fgets(userInput, (sizeof userInput) - 1, stdin); // Read user input including newline (ENTER)
  userInput[strlen(userInput) - 1] = '\0'; // Remove the \n at the end of the string

  named_array *words_list = NULL;
  for (int i = 0; i < ARRAY_COUNT(all_arrays); i++) {
    if(strcasecmp(userInput, all_arrays[i].name)==0) {
      words_list = &all_arrays[i];
      break; // Found something, stop searching
    }
  }

  if (words_list != NULL) {
    // Do something with the word list, for example search something in it
    for (int i = 0; i < words_list->count; i++) {
        printf("%s: %s\n", words_list->name, words_list->data[i]);
    }
  }
  else {
    printf("That is not a valid answer\n");
  }
}

int main(void) {
    question();
}
```

Answer (score 1):

C does not support that. You cannot identify and access at runtime a variable by its identifier you used in the program code.
This information is lost during compilation and linking, which are inherent to the language C being a compiled language. In other languages, notably those which are interpreted, it seems obvious; but compiled languages would need a feature called "introspection", i.e. knowing about compile-time aspects of the program.

You could search for the user input in an array similar to your `Animals` data, i.e. one which contains the topic names. Then use the same index to get to an array of arrays (or "2D") and find in there the array of infos relating to the topic (e.g. "Animals") in question. But that is not the same, the relevant difference is the necessary searching, which maps the input string to an index (or to the info that it is not valid... in case of e.g. "Mushrooms", which is none of your topics "Animals", "Clothes", "Fruit"...).

Answer (score 0):

Someone correct me if I'm wrong but you could do the look up based on this example:

```c
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

// NULL denotes the end of the list
const char *vocabulary_animals[4] = {"Eagle", "Cat", "Dog", NULL};
// NULL denotes the end of the list
const char *vocabulary_fruits[5] = {"Banana", "Apple", "Orange", "Pineapple", NULL};

const char **getVocabularyDictionary(const char *name) {
    if (strcasecmp(name, "animals") == 0) {
        return vocabulary_animals;
    } else if (strcasecmp(name, "fruits") == 0) {
        return vocabulary_fruits;
    }

    return NULL;
}

int main(void) {
    // "animals" can be user input
    const char *category = "animals";

    const char **words = getVocabularyDictionary(category);

    if (!words) {
        printf("Unknown category %s\n", category);

        return EXIT_FAILURE;
    }

    // loop through dictionary until it is empty (NULL)
    for (size_t i = 0; words[i]; ++i) {
        printf("Word %zu: %s\n", i, words[i]);
    }
}
```

My thoughts:

- `const char *words[]` instead of `char words[10][11]` because it makes it easier to deal with plus the words in the dictionary do not need to be mutable.
- `NULL` is used to denote the end of the array ([sentinel value](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sentinel_value)).
- This should give you an idea of how you can "dynamically" access *any* array at runtime: you need to map user inputs (whether that is a string, number etc.) to an object (pointer).
- Instead of manually checking for the right array, you could dynamically loop through a list that has the name included. (a `struct` could be used for example).

Comment: The approach seems generally viable, but this answer would be much improved by some prose explaining the approach and why something like it is needed.  Even so, however, I'm not sure why it was DVed.

Comment: @JohnBollinger I added some thoughts of mine. Did not want to add much because while there are multiple ways of solving this problem, the root of the problem is the same: you need to map some user input to the object you want to dynamically access. Whether you do that manually (like in my example) or through a list isn't that important.

Comment: Others have already pointed out that what OP wants is not directly possible with C, so I did not mention that fact.

Answer (score 0):

Try this.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

void getCategory() {
    char category[50]; // Assuming the category name won't exceed 50 characters

    // Prompt the user for the category of vocabulary
    printf("Enter the category of vocabulary you want to learn: ");
    fgets(category, sizeof(category), stdin);

    // Remove the trailing newline character from the input
    category[strcspn(category, "\n")] = '\0';

    // Display the chosen category
    printf("You have selected the category: %s\n", category);

    // You can now use the 'category' array for your game logic
}

int main() {
    // Your game's main logic can go here

    // Call the function to get the category from the user
    getCategory();

    // Continue with your game logic
    // ...

    return 0;
}
```

Added.

We have an array called categories that stores the vocabulary categories.
The getCategoryIndex function searches for a category that contains the typed vocabulary using strstr.

```
// Array of vocabulary categories
char categories[][50] = {
    "Animals",
    "Fruits",
    "Clothes",
    // Add more categories as needed
};

int getCategoryIndex(const char *input) {
    for (int i = 0; i < sizeof(categories) / sizeof(categories[0]); i++) {
        if (strstr(categories[i], input)) {
            return i;
        }
    }
    return -1; // Return -1 if no match is found
}
```